# PHP, SQL, загрузка данных на сайт, обновление данных

Tags: php, sql

Не могу разобраться с кодом на PHP. Вся суть в том, что нужно взять информацию из базы данных MS SQL server и загрузить ее на сайт. Проблема заключается в следующем. Первое фото загружается без проблем, но если пользователь добавляет или меняет его, скрипт не обновляет фотографию никак. Мой код:

```
// Generate Picture and Thumbnail

if (is_null($row['image_data'])) {
    $imgPath = "";
} else {
    $existQuery = "SELECT * FROM imagetrack WHERE pictureID = '" . $row['animal_id'] . "'";
    $existResult = mysql_query($existQuery);
    $existCheck = mysql_fetch_array($existResult);
    if ($existCheck['id'] && $existCheck['stampDate'] == $row['stamp'] && file_exists("./petUploads/images/".strtolower($animalType)."/".strtolower($animalStatus)."/thumbs/".$row['animal_id'].".jpg")) {
        $imgPath = $row['animal_id'].".jpg";
    } else {    
        if ($existCheck['id'] && $existCheck['stampDate'] != $row['stamp']) {
            unlink("./petUploads/images/".strtolower($animalType)."/".strtolower($animalStatus)."/".$row['animal_id'].".jpg");
            unlink("./petUploads/images/".strtolower($animalType)."/".strtolower($animalStatus)."/thumbs/".$row['animal_id'].".jpg");
        }
        $imgPath = $row['animal_id'].".jpg";
        createImage($animalType, $animalStatus, $row['image_data'], $row['animal_id']); 
        createThumbs("petUploads/images/".strtolower($animalType)."/".strtolower($animalStatus)."/","petUploads/images/".strtolower($animalType)."/".strtolower($animalStatus)."/thumbs/",150);
        if (!ftp_put($ftp_conn, $ftp_root . strtolower($animalType) . "/" . strtolower($animalStatus) . "/" . $imgPath, $site_root . strtolower($animalType) . "/" . strtolower($animalStatus) . "/" . $imgPath, FTP_BINARY) || !ftp_put($ftp_conn, $ftp_root . strtolower($animalType) . "/" . strtolower($animalStatus) . "/thumbs/" . $imgPath, $site_root . strtolower($animalType) . "/" . strtolower($animalStatus) . "/thumbs/" . $imgPath, FTP_BINARY)) {
            if (unlink("./petUploads/images/".strtolower($animalType)."/".strtolower($animalStatus)."/".$row['animal_id'].".jpg")) {
                $logMsg = "Error uploading, unlinking image for ".$row['animal_id'].".";
                $logQuery = "INSERT INTO log (date, message) VALUES(".date('d-m-Y h:i').", $logMsg)";
                mysql_query($logQuery);
            }
            if (unlink("./petUploads/images/".strtolower($animalType)."/".strtolower($animalStatus)."/thumbs/".$row['animal_id'].".jpg")) {
                $logMsg = "Error uploading, unlinking thumb image for ".$row['animal_id'].".";
                $logQuery = "INSERT INTO log (date, message) VALUES(".date('d-m-Y h:i').", $logMsg)";
                mysql_query($logQuery);
            }       
        } else {
            if ($existCheck['stampDate'] != $row['stamp']) {
                $delQuery = "DELETE FROM imagetrack WHERE pictureID = '". $row['animal_id'] . "'";
                mysql_query($delQuery);
            }
            $writeQuery = "INSERT INTO imagetrack (pictureID, stampDate) VALUES ('". $row['animal_id'] . "', '" . $row['stamp'] . "')";
            mysql_query($writeQuery);
        }               
    }
    $logQuery = "INSERT INTO log (date, message) VALUES (".date('d-m-Y h:i').", 'Animal ".$row['animal_id']." processed successfully')";
    mysql_query($logQuery);
} 

$i++;

if (is_null($row['feet'])) {
    $declawed = "No";
} else {
    $declawed = $row['feet'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        if ($existCheck['id'] && $existCheck['stampDate'] == $row['stamp'] && file_exists("./petUploads/images/".strtolower($animalType)."/".strtolower($animalStatus)."/thumbs/".$row['animal_id'].".jpg")) {
        $imgPath = $row['animal_id'].".jpg";
    } else {
```

Я не вижу у вас в коде блока, который отвечает за обновление добавление нового или изменение существующего фото. Если фото есть - то возвращается путь к картинке. Больше ничего в этом случае не происходит.

Comment: хотелось бы тогда его добавить, можете наставить на путь истинный?)

Comment: во-первых код очень запутанный, в нём сложно что-то менять ничего не сломав. Вначале я бы выделил из него отдельные функции

Comment: getImagePath, removeImage, uploadImage, shouldAddNewImage. Что делают функции думаю понятно по названию. Удостоверьтесь что код остался рабочим и ничего не сломалось. А дальше уже просто добавить новую логику - if(shouldAddNewImage()) {removeImage(); uploadImage(); getImagePath();); Как-то так.